# regex in SQL to detect one or more digit

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `shop` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE  '%[0-9]+ store%'
```

I wanted to match strings that says `'129387 store'`, but the above regex doesn't work. Why is that?

Comment: For those looking for Oracle SQL: use `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '.[0-9]+ store.')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [**REGEXP**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator instead of **LIKE** operator

Try this:

```
SELECT '129387 store' REGEXP '^[0-9]* store$';

SELECT * FROM shop WHERE `name` REGEXP '^[0-9]+ store$';
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92552/6)

**OUTPUT**

```
|         NAME |
|--------------|
| 129387 store |
```

Comment: This will allow `129387 something else store`.

Comment: @Barmar It will allow any `numeric string` at the start and after that ` store`.

Comment: No it doesn't. `.*` matches anything, so it will allow anything in between the numeric string and `store`.

Comment: You should use `+`, not `*`, because `*` allows zero repetitions. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/306adb/1

Answer (score 5):

If you mean MySQL, `LIKE` does not implement regular expressions. It implements the much more restricted SQL pattern matching, which just has two special operators: `%` matches any sequence of characters, and `_` matches any single character.

If you want regular expression matching, you must use the `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop
WHERE name REGEXP '[0-9]+ store'
```

MySQL's regular expression language doesn't include `\d` to specify digits, but you could write that as:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop
WHERE name REGEXP '[[:digit:]]+ store'
```

If the store name must begin with digits, you need an anchor:

```
SELECT *
FROM shop
WHERE name REGEXP '^[0-9]+ store'
```

You can learn more about regular expression syntax at [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info).

Comment: @kba Thanks, can't believe I did that!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `shop` 
WHERE  `name` LIKE  '%[0-9] store%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For those like me looking for Postgres:

Any digit:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `shop` 
WHERE  `name` ~ '\d'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `shop` 
WHERE  `name` ~ '[0-9]'
```

The OP question:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `shop` 
WHERE  `name` ~ '^\d+ store$'
```

There is a "SIMILAR TO" option in Postgres (but not MySQL) as well (`name SIMILAR TO '_*\d_*'`), but apparently it's basically just syntactic'ish sugar for regexp so it's recommended to use regexp instead: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/16892